# Prove $n! = o(n^n)$ without limits

Tags: asymptotics

I've already proven the statement using the limit definition of $o(g(n))$ and Stirling's approximation, but how do I prove it using the main definition for $o$ notation provided in CLRS instead?

Definition: $f(n) = o(g(n))$ if for all $c > 0$ there is $n_0 > 0$ such that $0 \leq f(n) < cg(n)$ for all $n > n_0$.

I've tried substituting Stirling's approximation again, but I am unaware of any analytic means of determining $n_0$ as a function of $c$ due to the presence of the $n$ term as both a base and exponent in the resulting inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need anything as fancy as Stirling. It is easy to see that $n!\cdot n < n^n$ for all $n>2$ (just compare the first two terms of $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots$ witht those of $n^n=n\cdot n\cdot\ldots$).

Comment: I missed completely that he asked the trivial question. Proving how n! is related to n^n e^-n, that would be a lot more tricky.

Comment: Prove that n! = o (n^n 2^-n): Split the product into the numbers 1 to n/8, n/8 to 2n/8, 2n/8 to 3n/8 etc.

Comment: I know it's easy to see that n! < n^n for all n > 2. My question wasn't what the general intuition behind the claim was. I was wondering how you would prove the claim formally using the definition I provided in my question. What would your choice of n_0 be for every choice of c? If c = 0.0001 for instance, then you can't say n! < cn^n simply "for all n>2".

Comment: @kotu You can just take $n_0>1/c$.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I'm unsure where you would go from there. If I let c > 0 be fixed and choose n_0 as you suggest, how do I exhibit the inequality n! < c * n^n for n > n_0? I apologize if I'm coming off as pedantic with these little details but I'd greatly appreciate it if you could update your answer with a full exposition.

Comment: @kotu I do not want to give a detailed exposition because I don't want to accidentally do someone's homework. If you let $n_0 > 1/c$ you just need to use elementary algebra on the expression $n!\cdot n <n^n$ to derive that $n!<cn^n$.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden many thanks, it seems painfully simple now that I finally understood that you were saying n! < 1/n n^n < c n^n for n > n_0 because n > n_0 > 1/c implies 1/n < c. This isn't a homework problem, but I can understand how the level of detail I'm asking for can make it seem as such. I just really struggle with the intution behind these "analysis"-type formal proofs of asymptotic equations. Could you explain your thought process for coming up with this solution? How did it occur to you to look at n!*n instead and choose your n_0?

Comment: @kotu I just needed any kind of separation between the functions. That $n!\cdot n < n^n$ occured to me after comparing the expansion of $n!$ and $n^n$ and it was the simplest inequality you can easily prove from comparing the expansions. To see that $n>1/c$ observe that $n^n$ is bigger than $n!$ by (at least) a factor of $n$. So, if we have a very small $c$ in front of $n^n$ - making it smaller by a factor $1/c$, we need to make it bigger by $1/c$ again by assuming $n>1/c$. It is essentially just the same as proving $n=o(n^2)$.